# Prolog - Find second and second last elements in list

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and currently stuck trying to understand how to implement this.
I need a predicate to find the second and the second last elements of a list using recursion, so for example:

`second_secondLast([1,2], X, Y).` must return X=2, Y=1.

`second_secondLast([1,2,3], X, Y).` must return X=2, Y=2.

`second_secondLast([1], X, Y).` must print 'Error' and return false.

First, I have the error-checking clauses:

```
second_secondLast([], X, Y) :- print("Error"), !, fail.
second_secondLast([_], X, Y) :- print("Error"), !, fail.
```

Next, I tried something like this:

```
second_secondLast([Y,X],X,Y) :- !.
second_secondLast(L, X, Y) :-
    second(L,X),
    secondLast(L,Y).

second([_,S|_], X) :- X = S.

secondLast([P,_], Y) :- Y = P.
secondLast([F|R], Y) :- secondLast(R, Y).
```

However, the output using [1,2,3] is `X=Y, Y=2.`
I'm not sure if it is possible to force the output to be `X=2` instead, or if there is a better method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the output `X=Y, Y=2.` has nothing to do with your program, it is an idiosyncracy of swipl (and maybe other interactive environments for Prolog implementations).

I think, your program looks fine, but you are asking for possible improvements.

`second([_,S|_], S).` is a more elegant version of  your `second([_,S|_], X) :- X = S.`.

Likewise, `secondLast([P,_], P).` is more elegant than your `secondLast([P,_], Y) :- Y = P.`.

I would also prefer `secondLast([_|R], Y) :- secondLast(R, Y).` to your
`secondLast([F|R], Y) :- secondLast(R, Y).`.

Your error-checking clauses look fine to me.

You could also get rid of the predicate `second` and alter the definition of  `second_secondLast` by using

```
second_secondLast([H,X|T], X, Y):-
   secondLast([H,X|T], Y).
```

instead of your

```
second_secondLast(L, X, Y) :-
    second(L,X),
    secondLast(L,Y).
```

That change would also make it a bit more efficient.
Another possibility is to use

```
second_secondLast(L, X, Y):-
    L= [_,X|_],
   secondLast(L, Y).
```

Then you could also get rid of the predicate `secondLast` and alter the above clause to

```
second_secondLast(L, X, Y):-
    L= [_,X|_],
   append(_, [Y,_], L).
```

.

There is always a ton of possibilities...